# python encoding problem when writing to rtf

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, rtf

I am using python3 and writing to rtf file with python, but some encoding issue is arising when using the char ø (also known as "\u00f8").
This is the code:

```
>>> myText = "a \u00f8 b"
>>> myText
'a ø b'

>>> out_file = open('test.rtf', 'w', encoding='utf8')
>>> textForFile = "{\\rtf1\\utf8 " + myText + "}"

>>> out_file.write(textForFile)
18
>>> out_file.close()
```

the file test.rtf now includes the following text:

```
a ˆ‚ b
```

instead of:

```
'a ø b'
```

Any idea what I'm missing in the encoding?

Comment: I think the issue is that do you open this file in utf-8 format? I mean your editor.

Comment: yes I am opening it using TextEdit on a mac, and according to Preferences it is using utf-8 encoding

Comment: @DevB2F Remove the `encoding='utf8'` and try. I tried this in windows and when i open the `.rtf` file, it is showing `a ø b`. When i use `encoding='utf8'` it is showing `a Ã¸ b`.

Comment: @DevB2F Do you have MS word installed ? Try with MS Word. If it still not showing the expected output, then we can label this as a macos TextEdit problem.

Comment: I open this file by sublime with utf-8 encoding,it works.

Comment: In TextEdit and LibreOffice the text is not showing correctly, in Sublime Text the following text is shown: {\rtf1\ansii a ø b} which is the RTF code, not formatted text

Answer (score 0):

The key to fix the problem was to encode the python file with cp1252 and use ansicpg1252 in the rtf code. I found the ansicpg1252 idea [in this documentation](http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/rtfspec_6.html). Now TextEdit, LibreOffice and OpenOffice all open the file correctly.

Correct code:

```
>>> myText = "a \u00f8 b"
>>> myText
'a ø b'
>>> out_file = open('test.rtf', 'w', encoding='cp1252')
>>> textForFile = "{\\rtf1\\ansicpg1252" + myText + "}"
>>> out_file.write(textForFile)
>>> out_file.close()
```